# flutter web auto_route: Maintenance Mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation, flutter-packages

How would I simple achive a "Maintenance-Mode"?

Hence: I have routes like:

`/` => `home`
`/contact` => `contact view`
`/about`=>`about view`

I tried to solve this by adding a guard to my first route (`/`) and in my resolver I push to `/maintenance`. Following the code example:

app_router.dart

```dart
part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@CupertinoAutoRouter(replaceInRouteName: 'View', 
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
  AutoRoute(page: HomeView, initial: true, path: HomeView.route, guards: [MaintenanceGuard]),
  AutoRoute(page: AboutView, path: AboutView.route),
  AutoRoute(page: ContactView, path: ContactView.route),
  AutoRoute(page: MaintenanceView, path: MaintenanceView.route),
])
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  AppRouter({required MaintenanceGuard maintenanceGuard}) : super(maintenanceGuard: maintenanceGuard); 
}
```

maintenance_guard.dart

```dart
class MaintenanceGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
    /// Proceed in debug mode
    if (kDebugMode) {
      resolver.next(true);
      return;
    }
    /// Redirect to maintenance view
    router.pushNamed(MaintenanceView.route);
  }
}
```

It works for `my-domain.com` and for `my-domain.com/`, but if I reload the page I get an 404 Error: `The requested URL was not found on this server`.

Same, if I directly insert the url `my-domain.com/maintenance`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using GetX. I store a boolean in the DB and have a Hasura subscription on it. As soon as it changes, the following controller gets called and the routing is being done.

```
class MaintenanceController extends GetxController {

      RxBool isMaintenance = false.obs;
    
      @override
      onInit() {
        super.onInit();
        ever(
            isMaintenance,
            (_) => {
                  if (isMaintenance.value) {Get.offNamed(Routes.maintenance)} else {Get.offNamed(Routes.splash)}
                });
      }
    }
```

The `ever()` method gets called whenever the value of the first parameter changes, and the second parameter gets executed. The method `onInit()` gets called upon the initialization of the controller. In my case, when I do   `Get.lazyPut(() => MaintenanceController());`
By doing this, I am able to force the app to move between the maintenance screen and the splash screen - where I do all the initialization (without forcing a restart which might not be accepted by Apple).